# Renaming a column in sql using jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I created a table (using NetBeans I went to Databases, into jdbc, into app and created a table). I am 80% sure this is a SQL table but I could be wrong.

I named one of my columns as secretQuestion but now I need to change it to securityQuestion.

I looked online and found the following:

```
ALTER table app.mytable CHANGE secretQuestion to securityQuestion;
ALTER table app.mytable RENAME secretQuestion to securityQuestion varchar (100);
```

neither CHANGE nor RENAME are recognized.

I am a slow-witted newbie so be very specific in your answer so that I can follow along!

I am using Derby!

Comment: Please post the code that shows how you execute these queries. Also, have you tested if these SQL statements work in your SQL IDE?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @RaviGold Which database management server you are using ?

Comment: Makes it difficult to answer. Do you know who installed your database? Have you heard of any of the following: Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL? Can you look at the SQL IDE properties and do they indicate which database you are using? What operating system are you using (so you may be able to take a look at running services or processes)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [here](https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/ref/index.html).

> **RENAME COLUMN statement**
>
> ***Syntax***
>
> `RENAME COLUMN table-Name.simple-Column-Name TO simple-Column-Name`
>
> ***Examples***
>
> To rename the manager column in table employee to supervisor, use the
>   following syntax:
>
> `RENAME COLUMN EMPLOYEE.MANAGER TO SUPERVISOR`

Answer (score 1):

i have one syntax please remove 'to' keyword. it worked for me. Be sure about the table name and old column name

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE name newname DATATYPE;
```

Comment: Still doesn't like the word change :(